# Lync SDK ModalityStateChanged status codes

Tags: lync, lync-2013, lync-2010, modality

I write program which uses lync 2013 via Lync 2013 SDK. I call (audio) to another users and I need to automatically detect the end of my call (drop after answered, voice mail, reject, no answer, invalid number). I use event of class AVModality ModalityStateChanged(object sender, ModalityStateChangedEventArgs e). Event data has NewState property of ModalityState enum type (which have only **disconnect** for the end of call), OldState property (the same type) and StatusCode property. I think if I want to detect the reason of the end of the call I should know possible status codes. Where can I find it? Or maybe there is another way to detect reason of the end of call Thanks.

```
private void ModalityStateChanged(object sender, ModalityStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewState == ModalityState.Disconnected && e.StatusCode == 1/*Status code*/)
        {
            //No answer. Do something

        }
        if (e.NewState == ModalityState.Disconnected && e.StatusCode == 2/*Status code*/)
        {
            //Voice mail. Do something

        }
    }
```